# Custom Taxonomy Template | WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I need some help regarding Custom Taxonomy. I have a website developed in WordPress and also have setup WooCommerce. I am using Kapee WordPress Theme. Now in that theme there is already a Taxonomy developed named **Brands**. I wanted to change the template of Single Brand Page. The URL should be like:
Website_Address/brand/**brand_name**

Now as I have multiple brands, I cannot develop a static template. I need to use the correct WordPress functions to make that page dynamic so every single brand page can have that layout. Now I have created a Custom taxonomy page, **taxonomy-product_brand.php**. THe page is opening correctly and I can see the Brand name in the breadcrumbs area and that is being loaded from the theme. Now I wanted to get all the data of the current page.

Can anyone please help me by sharing the code to get the data of the current **taxonomy-product_brand.php** page so I can make the page dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
echo print_r(get_queried_object());
```

More at:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/